# How do I use lxml and python to traverse the <body> of a html document along with its children

Tags: python, lxml

I would like to take an html document and traverse the `<body>` part of the document with its children. I see lots of examples to get a subtree via xpath or tag name but this doesn't seem to give the children.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html, etree  

html3 = "<html><head><title>test<body><h1>page title</h3><p>some text</p>"
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html3)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for el in root.iter():
    # do something
    print(el.text, tree.getpath(el))
```

This will output

```
None /html
None /html/head
test /html/head/title
None /html/body
page title /html/body/h1
some text /html/body/p
```

I would like only

```
page title /html/body/h1
some text /html/body/p
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: use bs4 library https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Yon only want to get the content between body tag, right?

Comment: @AlexLee yep content between the body tag.

Comment: @om-tripathi I would prefer not to use BS4 and figured there must be a way with lxml right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar difficulty, then I figured that each etree node has an iterator if its parent using which you can traverse

for instance, root here will give you the body using that you can iterate each element of body

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse('yourdocument.html', parser)

root = tree.xpath('/html/body/')[0]
for i in root.getiterator():
    print(i.tag,i.text)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I couldn't find :).  Should the xpath be:
    root = tree.xpath('/html/body')[0]

Comment: xpath can be any parent, better if you choose the lowest parent. In your case if its direct html to body then above will work. I suggest take the lowest parent. you can find that from inspect element

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your html code has an invalid format, I just wrote a little program with beautifuSoup that maybe you can use to modify for your purpose:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html3 = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><h1>page title</h1><p>some text</p><body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html3, "html5lib")
body = soup.find('body')

for item in body.findChildren():
    print(item)
```

Output

```
<h1>page title</h1>
<p>some text</p>
```